# why is my text and icon breaking?

Tags: html, css

Why is my icon and text not in same line though i have positioned them inside li with `display-line`

```
<div class="user">
  <ul>
   <li>         
     <i class="fa fa-2x fa-border fa-user"></i>              
     some text             
    </li>
 </ul>
</div>
```

I need to give a margin of 5px to my icon, so made it `position: absolute` because of it its now not placing it `inline`.

Why is my icon and text not in same line with a `margin of 5px` from top for the icon.

Below is the fiddle.

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/CjBhm

Comment: Why do you need position absolute on .fa-user? Removing position absolute fixes it?

Comment: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/HIafK Do you want this??

Comment: TOP TIP: Don't use CSS styles that you don't understand. Start with the minimum and then build, the key is to stop adding once you have what you want

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't use positioning, it isn't required in your case. I think you used to to align the icon in the right position but you can align *without* using `position: absolute;`

Now if you remove your positioning, the text will vertically align to the base, the reason is that `<i>` is an inline element which is aligned to *baseline* by default so you need to use `vertical-align: middle;`

[**Demo**](http://codepen.io/mr_alien/pen/hjmAc)

```
.fa-user {
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<div class="user">
  <ul>
    <li>         
      <i class="fa fa-2x fa-border fa-user">some text</i>             
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**It's not a good idea to use `<i></i>` tag without any text in between over here.**
I can only guess but soon you might use this link for redirecting to some other page, so this should happen when the person clicks on the hyperlink and not only the `fa-user` graphics as the later will make the text redundant.

For the css part,

**CSS**

```
ul li {
  display: inline-block;
}

.fa-user {
  margin: 5px;
}

.user {
  position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: Please refrain from posting code without any explanation. Teach a man to fish, @Ashesh.